# How can you remove all records from a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with about 50 tables having data in all but I want to remove those records so the database is like new, is there a way to do this or is there a way to extract the tables without the data?

Comment: Disable foreign key checks. Truncate all tables with according DELETE statements (iterate over INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, use dynamic SQL). Enable foreign key checks back.

Comment: Another option: backup the database specifying structure only (for example, by mysqldump with --no-data option), also backup procedures/functions/triggers, drop database, restore empty database from the backup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DROP](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-drop-all-tables.html) command to remove the tables

If you want to keep table schema but delete all records use

[TRUNCATE](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-truncate-table#:%7E:text=The%20TRUNCATE%20statement%20in%20MySQL,without%20removing%20the%20table%20structure.) command.

Comment: i want to keep the tables but remove every record from each table

Comment: Use TRUNCATE command [Link](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-truncate-table#:~:text=The%20TRUNCATE%20statement%20in%20MySQL,without%20removing%20the%20table%20structure.)